# Why doesn' t this code generate a log file?

Tags: python

Why isn't this code creating a log file? It used to work... I ran it from command line and debugger vscode...

I have logged at info and error level and still nothing.

Seems like an empty file should at least be created.. .but then again, maybe python does a lazy create.

```
import logging
import argparse
import datetime
import sys
import platform

def main():
    print("something")
    logging.error("something")

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    the_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    msg = "Start time: {}".format(the_time)
    print(msg)
    logging.info(msg)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='validation')
    parser.add_argument("-L", "--log", help="log level", required=False, default='INFO')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    numeric_level = getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None)
    print(numeric_level)
    if not isinstance(numeric_level, int):
        raise ValueError('Invalid log level: %s' % args.log.upper())
    print("setting log level to: {} for log file validate.log".format(args.log.upper()))
    logging.basicConfig(filename='validate.log', level=numeric_level, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    logging.info("Python version: {}".format(sys.version))

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the function [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) says:

> This function **does nothing** if the root logger **already has handlers configured**, unless the keyword argument `force` is set to `True`.

Now, does your root logger has handlers? **Initially, no**. However, when you call any of the log functions (`debug`, `info`, `error`, etc.), it **creates a default handler**. Therefore, calling `basicConfig` after these functions **does nothing**.

Running this program

```
print(logging.getLogger().hasHandlers())
logging.error('test message')
print(logging.getLogger().hasHandlers())
```

produces:

```
$ python3 test.py
   False
   ERROR:root:test message
   True
```

To fix your issue, just add `force=True` as an argument for `basicConfig`.